# htaccess http to https with www. Without redirecting sub domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a `RewriteRule` that redirects my main domain to `https://www.sta-games.com` which works fine, but when I try to access my subdomain `http://files.sta-games.com`, it redirects to my main domain.

Heres my redirect rules

```
#HTTPS Redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: The second condition and rule declare that, if the host does not start with `www.`, a redirect to the `https://www.` domain will be performed.

Comment: Your rules look fine. Test this in Chrome dev tool and see what redirects are you getting.

Comment: I tried, but it the domain changes to `https://www.files.sta-games.com` and the page shows my main page

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your rules so that it looks for the whole domain instead of just part of it. Right now you are only looking for the absence of `www`. So that is why your subdomain redirects.

First you need to combine your rules because it seems you want to redirect if https is not on and there is no `www`, so make that one rule. Then use your actual domain name in the rule. Replace example.com with your domain. This should fix your issue.

```
#HTTPS Redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an additional skip condition for all domains except the main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sta-games\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.sta-games.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.