# .htaccess HTTPS Main Domain & Wildcard HTTP Sub-Domains + All Non-WWW

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

There are many similar solutions on Stack Overflow such as [htaccess http to https with www. Without redirecting sub domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242495/htaccess-http-to-https-with-www-without-redirecting-sub-domain).

What I need, however, is:

- Main domain HTTPS + NON-WWW
- Wildcard HTTP for ALL sub-domains instead of adding one after another.

I am running a WordPress Multisite website and have no wildcard SSL.

I am using the following at the moment:

**Non-WWW**

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Non-WWW and Non-HTTPS Sub-Domains**

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain1.main.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain2.main.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain3.main.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain4.main.com
```

**SSL**

```
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# www is redirected to base domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# base domain should use HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# other domain should use HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks! No, it does not work unfortunately. The moment I add it everything goes to HTTPS even though the WWW is removed.

Comment: I forgot to tag you on my comment above.