# htaccess https for main and http for subs

Tags: .htaccess, https, subdomain

I am using this htaccess code to redirect the main domain to https and all subs to http:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# www is redirected to base domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# base domain should use HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# other domain should use HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

An answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37939038/8954791).

It works fine, but I would like to have as base domain the www. in front of the domain. How does this works. Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the next two lines below `# www is redirected to base domain`

Comment: No, this redirect me to http